# Documentation tag versions with Sphinx

Tags: python, versioning, python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx underneath to generate documentation for my project.
How do I generate multiple versions based on tags/branches?

I did check the library `sphinxcontrib-versioning` but as it is not updated recently, It seems broken. Anything I can look into? Can anyone direct me to source?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to publish multiple versions of your docs, using Pyramid and Read the Docs as an example.

Compare [`conf.py` on the `master` branch](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/docs/conf.py) with other numbered branches.  The versions are pretty much the same, except for [older versions](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.9-branch/) we slap on a fixed div that says "Read the latest version of this page" and links to the latest stable version, and for the [master branch](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/) we slap on a warning badge "NOTICE Documentation in Progress".

Then [configure RTD to build multiple versions](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/versions.html) of your docs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am facing an issue where creation of document for particular tags/branches fails due to changed import on my tutorials python file (seems like it run on current version of project rather than that particular version). Is their a way we can ignore these Sphinx error and go and create documentation anyway? using sphinxcontrib-versioning

Comment: You must fix your imports.